# Show error while converting Python 2 to Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, python-memcached

**I am converting Python 2 to 3. When converting, I receive this error:**

> AssertionError: No API proxy found for service "memcache"

**This exception occurs when creating the following class.**

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb

from api import fields
import config
import model
import util


class Config(model.Base, model.ConfigAuth):
```

---

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb

class Base(ndb.Model):
```

Can I use *google.appengine.ext* in Python 3, like in Python 2? What is the API proxy?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Google App Engine Bundled Services/API is supported for Python 3.

Take a look at the instructions [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-python-standard).

**Note:** You'll have to run your App with `dev_appserver.py` else you'll get errors that look like

```
google.appengine.runtime.apiproxy_errors.RPCFailedError: Attempted RPC call without active security ticket
```

Comment: This is a flask app and when running on google app engine wrapping app with wrap_wsgi_app() I still receive the error

Comment: Are you saying you're still getting the ```No API proxy found for service "memcache"``` error? Did you run your app with ```dev_appserver.py```?

Comment: Yes still getting the error. I'm trying to run in the cloud environment.

Comment: Don't know what you mean by you're trying to run in the cloud environment. Please, explain.

Comment: I am running in google app engine on google cloud.

Comment: Just to be clear. You're saying - you deployed your code to Production (e.g. you used ```gcloud app deploy```), and then you get the above error in Production?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257221/discussion-between-nocommandline-and-ffejrekaburb).