# Memcache Error with python2 to python 3 conversion

Tags: google-app-engine

I have set the following variables in app.yaml.

```
env_variables:
CURRENT_VERSION_TIMESTAMP: "1677721600"
MEMCACHE_USE_CROSS_COMPATIBLE_PROTOCOL: 'True'
NDB_USE_CROSS_COMPATIBLE_PICKLE_PROTOCOL: 'True'
DEFERRED_USE_CROSS_COMPATIBLE_PICKLE_PROTOCOL: 'True'
```

inside my main.py I have the following commands

```
from google.appengine.api import users
from google.appengine.api import wrap_wsgi_app

app.wsgi_app = wrap_wsgi_app(app.wsgi_app)
```

[1] - Python 3 https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/services/access

When I run I get the following error

```
File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.12/site-packages/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 69, in CreateRPC
 assert stub, 'No api proxy found for service "%s"' % service
AssertionError: No api proxy found for service "memcache"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show error while converting Python 2 to Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78177673/show-error-while-converting-python-2-to-python-3)